# Camera Preview distorted

Tags: android, camera

I cannot help myself anymore, I have read every thread about this on stackoverflow, but nothing would fix my problem.

I try to set up my camera preview in a FrameLayout, everything works fine. I determine the correct size for the preview with this code:

```
private Camera.Size getBestPreviewSize(int width, int height,
                                           Camera.Parameters parameters) {
    Camera.Size result = null;
    for (Camera.Size size : parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes()) {
        if (size.width <= width && size.height <= height) {
            if (result == null) {
                result = size;
            } else {
                int resultArea = result.width * result.height;
                int newArea = size.width * size.height;
                if (newArea > resultArea) {
                    result = size;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return (result);
}
```

Afterwards I apply it to my camera:

```
Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
Camera.Size size = getBestPreviewSize(width, height, params);
params.setPreviewSize(size.width, size.height);
params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
mCamera.setParameters(params);
```

The Preview is still distorted afterwards, and my FrameLayout, which I expected to have the same size as the Preview Size I calculated, remains Fullscreen.

Fullscreen means 1920x1200
Preview Size means 1920x1080

So what I did is I set my Size of the FrameLayout manually to the calculated Preview Size. Then, however, my Preview looks even more skewed.

I have no idea what I am doing wrong. I thought when I use a supported Preview Size, this should not happen.

**UPDATE:**

I ran my application on another device, there everything works fine. Can this be a hardware bug? The device that is not working for me is the Nexus 7 Tablet.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally come to a solution, this is really related to the hardware. There is a bug with some devices:

[Bug-Report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=73316)

**The workaround:**

> This is a known low-level issue with some devices; they require that the still picture size and the preview size have matching aspect ratios, to avoid stretching artifacts.
>
> If possible for your application, match the aspect ratios for setPreviewSize and setPictureSize.

Hope this helps you as well!